# C# - Encoding.ASCII.GetString() returns "??" instead of actual string, why?

Tags: c#

This is my piece of code (file is a `HttpPostedFileBase` type):

```
var imageStream = file.InputStream;
var header = new Byte[4];
imageStream.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
```

Now, while my code runs, i place a breakpoint, and in my immediate window i check values:

```
header
{byte[4]}
    [0]: 255
    [1]: 216
    [2]: 255
    [3]: 224
```

But, when i want to convert this byte array to string of ASCII, i get this (values obtained by immediate window):

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header)
"????"
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header, 0, 2)
"??"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ASCII = 7 bit encoding, therefore numbers>127 are not part of the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 5):

Characters above 127 cannot be represented as ASCII (which is a 7-bit encoding), and are therefore turned into `?`.

What are you trying to achieve? There are many other encodings which may be more suitable for what you're trying to do - or no encoding at all maybe. It is important to understand that a char is not equivalent to a byte.

If the header is a "fixed" 4-byte sequence, don't use characters but rather the bytes directly (or an integer representation - see the BitConverter class for converting byte arrays to other things).

Comment: I want it to become a string, so i can use an .StartsWith() method on it.

Comment: @ojek, if you want it to be a string, you need to know what the mapping between the single bytes (8-bit) and the unicode charpoints (16-bit) are - oitherwise a string comparison doesn't work. That's why you need to pick the appropriate encoding, or avoid strings altogether and compare plain bytes.

Answer (score 3):

ASCII character codes are in the range 0 to 127 inclusive. Your data is outside that range. Hence the attempt to interpret the data as ASCII fails. The `?` characters are used to indicate characters that could not be decoded.

The first 4 bytes, in hex, are

```
FF D8 FF E0
```

That's the header for a [JPEG file](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html).

So, converting these bytes into a string is just not the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 1):

It is because these characters are not printable using ASCII - try using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(header)` instead.

EDIT:
As utilising UTF8 blindly seems inappropriate, you could perhaps try the following:-
`Request.ContentEncoding.GetString(header)` which should utilise the encoding configured in the request.

Comment: What makes you think that those bytes are encoded in UTF8?

Comment: A fair point - but who says they arent? ;-)

Comment: Well, they aren't, are they? I have a particular distaste for trial and error programming. Which is what you are advocating.

Comment: It is a filestream, i have no idea how are they encoded.

Comment: I have just edited the answer - hope it helps

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why didn't you tell us right away..?

Comment: @PaulMichalik I told you as soon as I realised myself.

Comment: What's more, it's not that these values are not printable. In fact, these values are not valid ASCII.